# Powershell, Tying 2 variables together in one script

Tags: powershell

I have the following script.  It is getting me a system array.  I need to tie the $id variable and the $upn variable together with each iteration.  I am at a loss on how to get the loop to continue through and tie the 2 variables together.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
$adroles = get-mgdirectoryrole | select displayname,Id
$upn = foreach ($id in $adroles.id) { 
    Get-mgdirectoryrolemember -DirectoryRoleId $id | 
        select-object -expandproperty additionalproperties |
            foreach-object -membername userPrincipalName
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "tie the $id variable and the $upn variable together"? What is the `$upn` variable? Are you wanting something like a key-value relationship or are you looking for more of a [tuple](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/using-a-tuple-in-powershell/)?

Comment: I would like my output to be $id + $upn for each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking to *merge* the output from [`Get-MgDirectoryRole`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.identity.directorymanagement/get-mgdirectoryrole?view=graph-powershell-1.0) with the output from [`Get-MgDirectoryRoleMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.identity.directorymanagement/get-mgdirectoryrolemember?view=graph-powershell-1.0), if that's the case this is how you can do it:

```
Get-MgDirectoRyrole | ForEach-Object {
    foreach($upn in (Get-MgDirectoryRoleMember -DirectoryRoleId $_.Id).additionalProperties.userPrincipalName) {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            DisplayName       = $_.DisplayName
            Id                = $_.Id
            UserPrincipalName = $upn
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You made that look so much more simple than I was doing.  Thank you.  I will accept your answer as soon as I am allowed to.

Comment: @Sean glad it helped :) in case you need to export that to CSV you can simply pipe the end of the `ForEach-Object` loop to `Export-Csv` in case you need me to add that to my answer let me know

Comment: Thank you.  I could get that far LOL.  I was just having fit trying to get the data where I wanted it.  However, your answer really taught me a lot and I can't thank you enough.